# ANOVA: which test is to be chosen when they differ in significance?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, bonferroni

I am using the software PAST*.
When running an ANOVA I have available these tests: Tuckey's pairwise, Kruskal-Wallis, Mann-Whitney pairwise and Dunn's post hoc.
I am trying to see if three species are different.
In one case the species A is significantly different from species B using the Mann-Whitney pairwise (p=0,01839 Bonferroni corrected) but not different using the Dunn's post hoc (p=0,1616 Bonferroni corrected) and Tuckey's pairwise (p=0,4652).

In these cases, is there a rationale to choose one of these tests and to accept/reject the hypothesis that the species are different?

*:https://www.nhm.uio.no/english/research/resources/past/index.html
https://paleo.carleton.ca/2001_1/past/past.pdf
"A comprehensive, but simple-to-use software package for executing a range of standard numerical  analysis  and  operations  used  in  quantitative  paleontology  has been developed. ... PAST  integrates  spread-sheet-type  data  entry  with  univariate  and  multivariate  statistics,  curve  fitting,  time-series analysis, data plotting, and simple phylogenetic analysis. Many of the functions are specific to paleontology and ecology, and these functions are not found in standard, more extensive, statistical packages."

Comment: Can you add a reference/link for software PAST? Never heard of it

Comment: https://www.nhm.uio.no/english/research/resources/past/index.html
https://paleo.carleton.ca/2001_1/past/past.pdf

Comment: Pleas include this new information as an edit to the post, on this site comments are ephemeral and often overlooked. Then, please also directly quote the most important part of the document!